# Differenza tra "soffrire" e "subire"

Tags: difference, vocabulary

Non so qual è la differenza tra il verbo "soffrire" ed il verbo "subire" giacché in spagnolo c'è soltanto un verbo per tradurre entrambi.

Comment: Hai cercato su un vocabolario monolingue italiano come il [Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/) o il [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/)? C'è qualcosa in particolare che non ti è chiaro nelle loro spiegazioni?

Comment: Sei sicuro che in spagnolo la parola sia la stessa? ***soffrire*** - http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano-Spagnolo/parola/s/soffrire.aspx?query=soffrire-  ***subire*** http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano-Spagnolo/parola/S/subire.aspx?query=subire

Answer (score 3):

Il verbo *subire* è più neutro rispetto a *soffrire*. *Soffrire* implica una sensazione negativa da parte della persona coinvolta. Invece, *subire* mette in evidenza la passività della persona rispetto all'azione e implica la presenza di un agente esterno, mentre non implica necessariamente un'emozione negativa.

Infatti si dice ***soffrire*** di una malattia cardiaca ma, ad esempio, ***subire*** un'intervento chirurgico. Invertendo i contesti i due verbi risultano  inappropriati: non si può dire **subire una malattia* o **soffrire un intervento chirurgico*

Comment: Tendenzialmente direi “soffrire *di* una malattia”.

Comment: sì, è un *lapsus calami*

Comment: Grazie mille! Secondo questa spiegazione si subisce discriminazione, certo? Qualche volta ho letto soffrire di discriminazione (di genere, ad esempio)

Comment: In questo caso entrambe le costruzioni sono possibili, perché registrano aspetti diversi dell'evento: hai subito una discriminazione e per questo motivo hai sofferto. Invece non direi direttamente "soffrire la discriminazione".

Comment: @IvanFD inoltre, per chiedere conferma di un'ipotesi, si dice "giusto?" e non "certo?" :)